# Como filtrar uma APIView para mostrar as mensagens relacionadas a um utilizador?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Eu quero criar uma view usando APIView, que mostre todas as mensagens enviadas por um utilizador especificado no url.

models.py:

```
class Message(models.Model):
body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
normaluser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Como User estou a utilizar a tabela User providenciada pelo Django.

views.py:

```
class MessageUserView(APIView):
def get(self, request, pk): # devolve objecto
    normaluser = MessageSerializer(instance=Message.objects.get(normaluser),
    many=False)
    serializer = MessageSerializer(instance=Message.objects.filter(pk=normaluser), 
    many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Neste momento ao executar o código dá-me o seguinte erro:

> UnboundLocalError at /website/message-user/2 local variable
>   'normaluser' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

O erro que esta recebendo, é um erro de syntax do Python, pois esta tentando usar `normaluser` na declaração de `normaluser` sem previamente ter criado `normaluser`, basicamente!

Sobre o filtro que deseja fazer, a própria [documentação](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) do `DRF` tem exemplos para tal, seja pela URL passando um "user id" como demonstra seu exemplo, quanto pelo objeto `request` do Django, que contém o usuario autenticado.

Veja:

```
from myapp.models import Purchase
from myapp.serializers import PurchaseSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser=user)
```

Aconselho dar uma olhada [aqui](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user) para maiores detalhes e exemplos.

Att,